# SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' when trying to add Cesium to a React Redux application

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, react-redux, cesiumjs

I am trying to add Cesium JS library to a React-Redux application and it keeps spitting out the error *SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@'*. I have tried multiple ways to do this and the same error occurs.

I am not sure why it is having an issue as the file the error is referring to was auto generated by *npm install cesium*. The problem file is *node_modules\cesium\Source\Widgets\widgets.css*. The CSS file contains a bunch of import CSS links that looks like *@import url(./Viewer/Viewer.css);*.

If anyone has any idea how to solve this error (commenting out that file just causes more errors) or maybe a method to add Cesium library to a React-Redux application that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you followed the Webpack instructions on the Cesium site at https://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/cesium-and-webpack/ , or possibly the examples in my blog post at https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/03/declarative-earth-part-1-cesium-webpack/ ?

Comment: Yes, my colleague and I have followed that tutorial and still ran into errors.